# Why does screen captures get a better quality than saving (EPS to JPEG)

Tags: image-quality, jpg, eps, screen-printing, irfanview

I have EPS files containing photographs that I can’t open in Isodraw for an unknown reason.

I’m converting them to JPEG (with Irfanview, quality 100) and experience a significant loss of quality which is normal.

What I don’t understand is that, when I zoom in a do a screen capture of the image that I save in JPEG too, the quality of the picture is better.

Can you help me understand that?

Comment: Well *zooming* and taking a screenshot is obviously going to be better than a JPG with no zoom. What format are your screenshots? Mac screenshots are PNG for example, which again is likely to be better than JPG

Comment: Sidenote: One way to obtain the pictures at full quality (i.e., as they are stored in the EPS) is to open them in a vector-graphics software (e.g., Inkscape is a free one) and just copy and paste the image to whereever you want to use it.

Comment: @Cai I was saving the screenshots in JPEG. Turns out that I have an even better quality using an online converter so that means that irfanview doesn't output the best quality possible when selecting 100.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft I did try to open it with Inkscape too but it wouldn't open either (a similar error with isodraw). I guess there is a problem with the file that irfanview doesn't care about.

Comment: Not all rendering engines are born equal. The compression quality is most likely the least of your issues. Pictures would help heaps.